# Add “Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?” when writing a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, confirmation

When I'm writing a comment on **skeptics.se**, it takes a lot of time to create it and fix it and I use all the characters allowed that it looks like a small paragraph.

Usually you have to link studies, and academic articles, etc...

Many times, my browser went back automatically when pressing backspace (to delete something), and (on my macbook if you slide two fingers on the left of the pad, it will go back), it is really annoying and it happened with me many times.

The comment will be ereased and I would have to re-write it again.

Please add:

> You haven't posted your comment yet, are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?

when trying to navigate away from a page with an unposted comment.

Comment: Write the comment in notepad or something, then paste it in the comment box...

Comment: Shouldn't I write it on paper before? Just to make sure notepad won't crash?

Comment: No, a better way is learning how to use the backspace and Mac gestures..

Comment: Well writing it on paper works, but really, how often does text edit crash?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazarus-form-recovery/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno?hl=en may work, I'm not sure